# Building Angular CLI theme

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've purchased an angular-cli based theme from themeforest, before purchasing I thought there will be a pure html/css version (including some js libraries) but I was wrong.

As I'm not familiar with angular-cli I want to know if it is possible to build/export this theme as simple html/css files?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you bought a theme that is build on top of Angular, right?

Well, when we build the Angular code it generates a set of files in js, HTML and CSS. However, it's not for you code on it. Usually, we build the application to serve it in the production. As your project is based on Angular, I think you must code using the framework.

If you're not familiar with the framework and don't want to learn it, I strongly recommend you to buy a new theme or to use a free one. I'd suggest you to use the [coreui](https://coreui.io) theme. They have it for pure HTLM, js and CSS.